# Combinatorics: How many ways to form a group of $k$ elements out of other groups?

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say you have a number of groups that contain a variable amount of elements. For example, taking colored balls and assume you have $3$ different groups of those, consisting of the following items:

Group 1: Black ball $1$, Black ball $2$, Black ball $3$

Group 2: Orange ball $1$

Group 3: Yellow ball $1$, Yellow ball $2$, Yellow ball $3$, Yellow ball $4$

Now I'm interested in forming a group that has $k$ elements in total, for example $4$; so I want to form groups consisting of no more and no less than $4$ balls in total.

How many ways are there to form such groups, given the available colored balls? For example, one result might be:

Orange ball $1$, Yellow ball $1$, Yellow ball $2$, Black ball $1$

The colors themselves are not distinguishable, so this outcome should be the same as Orange ball $1$, Yellow ball $1$, Yellow ball $3$ (!), Black ball $1$ for example, and hence not be counted again.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I don't really know how to approach this one anymore - have been dealing with combinatorics last 10 years ago, and this is a small part of a larger IT problem I'm currently working on, I'm fairly helpless at the moment

Comment: You can just simply count the number of ways, its very straightforward.

Comment: Hi @NewGuy, thanks - not quite sure I understand. Count as in, manually? In this example, sure; though I'm looking for a generalized solution that would work with an arbitrary number of groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll reword your question a bit. Let me know if I have not framed it properly.

> Say we have a collection of $r$ unique elements each of which occurs in multiple copies. Namely, our collection has $n_1$ identical copies of $X_1$, $n_2$
>   identical copies of $X_2$, $\ldots$, and $n_r$ identical copies of
>   $X_r$. 
>   How many ways can we form combinations of length $k$, where repeated copies of unique elements are allowed?

This question has a standard answer which can be derived [informally](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2509842/combination-for-subset-with-duplicates) and also formally (see below). In either case the answer is

$$
\sum_{\ell=0}^{r} (-1)^{\ell} \sum_{\textbf{j} \in \{n_k\}_{\ell} } \binom{k+r-1 - \sum_{i=1}^{\ell}(j_i +1)}{r-1}
$$

where $\{n_k\}_{\ell}$ is the set of all $\ell$-length combinations of the elements $(n_1, \ldots, n_r)$, $\textbf{j} = (j_1, j_2, \ldots, j_{\ell})$ is a vector representing a particular element of the set of $\{n_k\}_{\ell}$, and the second summation is over all such combinations. (The $\ell=0$ term simply reduces to "$k+r-1$ choose $r-1$".)

We can apply the above formula to your example. In your case you have $r=3$ types of elements and you're trying to form combinations of length $k=4$. We identify the blue, orange, and yellow balls with $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$ respectively. We then have $n_1 = 3$, $n_2 = 1$, and $n_3 =4$. The possible values of $\textbf{j}$ with defined by various $\ell$ are

\begin{eqnarray}
\ell = 1: & \quad j_1 & \in \{3, 1, 4\} \\
\ell = 2: & \quad  (j_1, j_2) & \in \{(3, 1), (1,4), (4, 3)\} \\
\ell = 3: & \quad (j_1, j_2, j_3) & \in \{(3, 1, 4) \}
\end{eqnarray}

We thus find 
\begin{eqnarray}
& & \binom{4+3-1}{3-1} - \Big[ \binom{4+3-1 -(3+1)}{3-1} +\binom{4+3-1 -(1+1)}{3-1}+\binom{4+3-1 -(4+1)}{3-1}\Big] \\
& & + \Big[ \binom{4+3-1 -(4+2)}{3-1} +\binom{4+3-1 -(5+2)}{3-1}+\binom{4+3-1 -(7+2)}{3-1}\Big]\\
& &- \Big[ \binom{4+3-1 -(8+3)}{3-1}\Big]\\
& = & \binom{6}{2} - \Big[\binom{2}{2} + \binom{4}{2}+ 0\Big] +\Big[0\Big] - 0 = 8, 
\end{eqnarray} 
where we used $\binom{n}{k} = 0$ if $n>k$. This result can be checked by listing the number of ways to form the elements.

---

**Formal Derivation**

To derive the general answer to the highlighted question,  we note that the desired number is equal to the number of ways $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_r$ can all sum to $k$ where each $\alpha_k$ (i.e., the number of elements of $X_k$) runs from $0, 1, \ldots, n_k$. Namely, we want to compute 
$$
(\#)_{n_1,\ldots, n_r; k} = \sum_{\alpha_1=0}^{n_1}\cdots \sum_{\alpha_r=0}^{n_r} \delta_{k, \alpha_1+\cdots +\alpha_r},
$$
where $\delta_{\ell, m}$ is the Kronecker delta.  To compute the above quantity, we need to use two identities both of which are established by the [Cauchy's Integral Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula):

$$ 
\delta_{m, \ell} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{dz}{z} z^{m-\ell}, \qquad \binom{k}{\ell} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C dz\, \frac{z^{k}}{(z-1)^{\ell +1}}.
$$
Using the contour integral representation of the Kronecker delta, we have

\begin{align}
(\#)_{n_1,\ldots, n_r; k} & =  \sum_{\alpha_1=0}^{n_1} \cdots \sum_{\alpha_{r}=0}^{n_r} \oint_C \frac{dz}{z} z^{k- \alpha_1- \cdots - \alpha_r}\\
& =  \oint_C \frac{dz}{z} z^{k} \prod_{m=1}^{r} \sum_{\alpha_m=0}^{n_m} z^{-\alpha_k}  \quad \text{[Commute summation and integral]} \\
& =  \oint_C \frac{dz}{z} z^{k} \prod_{m=1}^{r} \frac{1-z^{-n_m-1}}{1-z^{-1}} \quad \text{[Geometric Series Identity]}  \\
& = \oint_C dz  \frac{z^{k+r-1}}{(z-1)^r} \prod_{m=1}^{r} \left(1- z^{-1} z^{-n_k}\right).
\end{align}

Now, using the identity 
\begin{equation}
\prod_{i=1}^N(1+\lambda x_i) = \sum_{\ell=0}^{N} \lambda^{\ell} \Pi_{\ell}(x_1, \ldots, x_N), 
\end{equation}
where $\Pi_{\ell}(x_1, \ldots, x_N)$ is the $\ell$th [elementary symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) in the variables $(x_1, \ldots, x_N)$, we find 
\begin{align}
(\#)_{n_1,\ldots, n_r; k} 
& =  \sum_{\ell=0}^{r}(-1)^{\ell}\,\oint_C dz  \frac{z^{k+r-1- \ell}}{(z-1)^r} \, \Pi_{\ell}(z^{-n_1}, \ldots, z^{-n_r}).
\label{eq:omegpre}
\end{align}
For an arbitrary elementary symmetric polynomial we have the definition 
\begin{equation}
\Pi_{\ell}(x_1, x_2,  \ldots, x_r) = \sum_{ \textbf{j} \in \{1, 2, \ldots, r\}_{\ell} } x_{j_1} x_{j_2}\cdots x_{j_{\ell}},
\end{equation}
where $\textbf{j} = (j_1, \ldots, j_{\ell})$ is a particular combination of length $\ell$ of the elements in $\{1, 2, \ldots, r\}$ and the summation is over all combinations of length $\ell$. For our case, we similarly have 
\begin{equation}
\Pi_{\ell}(z^{-n_1}, \ldots, z^{-n_r}) = \sum_{ \textbf{j} \in \{n_k\}_{\ell} } z^{- j_1 - \ldots - j_{\ell}}.
\end{equation}
$(\#)_{n_1,\ldots, n_r; k} $ therefore becomes 
\begin{align}
(\#)_{n_1,\ldots, n_r; k}
& =  \sum_{\ell=0}^{r}(-1)^{\ell}\, \sum_{ \textbf{j} \in \{n_m\}_{\ell} }\oint_C dz \, \frac{z^{k+r-1- \ell}}{(z-1)^r} \,z^{- j_1 - \ldots - j_{\ell}} \\
& = \sum_{\ell=0}^{r}(-1)^{\ell}\, \sum_{ \textbf{j} \in \{n_m\}_{\ell} }\oint_C dz\,  \frac{z^{k+r-1- \sum_{i=1}^{\ell}(j_i +1)}}{(z-1)^r}.
\end{align}
Using the contour integral representation of the binomial, we ultimately find 
\begin{equation}
(\#)_{n_1,\ldots, n_r; k} =  \sum_{\ell=0}^{r}(-1)^{\ell}\, \sum_{ \textbf{j} \in \{n_m\}_{\ell} } \binom{k+r-1 - \sum_{i=1}^{\ell}(j_i +1)}{r-1},
\label{eq:omeggen}
\end{equation}
where $j_1, \ldots, j_{\ell}$ is a particular combination of $\ell$ elements in $\{n_1, \ldots, n_r\}$ and the second summation runs over all such combinations.

---

**Some Special Cases**

1. For $n_k=1$ for all $k$, $\{n_1, \ldots, n_r\}$ becomes the $r$ element set $\{1, \ldots, 1\}$. Thus summing over all $\ell$-length combinations of $\{n_1, \ldots, n_r\}$ reduces to setting $j_i= 1$ for all $i$ and multiplying the relevant term by the number of ways to choose $\ell$ elements from a set of $r$ elements, i.e., $\binom{r}{\ell}$. We thus find 
   \begin{equation}
   (\#)_{n_1,\ldots, n_r; k} =  \sum_{\ell=0}^{r}(-1)^{\ell}\, \binom{r}{\ell} \binom{k+r-1 - 2\ell}{r-1}.
   \end{equation}
   However, if all $n_m$ are equal to 1, then the number of ways we can choose combinations of length $k$ from the elements $A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_r$ is simply the number of ways to choose $k$ elements from a set of $r$ elements. Thus we can conclude 
   \begin{equation}
   \sum_{\ell=0}^{r}(-1)^{\ell}\, \binom{r}{\ell} \binom{k+r-1 - 2\ell}{r-1} = \binom{r}{k}. 
   \end{equation}
2. For $n_m = \infty$ for al $m$, then $j_i = \infty$ for all $i$ and all terms in \refew{omeggen} are zero except for $\ell=0$. (The binomial $\binom{n}{k}$ is zero whenever $n< k$). We thus have 
   \begin{equation}
   (\#)_{n_1,\ldots, n_r; k} = \binom{k+r-1}{r-1},
   \end{equation}
   which matches the standard result (see "[Combination with repetitions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208377/combination-with-repetitions)" for example).
3. For $n_m = n$ for all $m$, then $j_i = n$ for all $i$. Similar to the case in 1., summing over over all $\ell$-length combinations of $\{n_1, \ldots, n_r\}$ reduces to setting $j_i= n$ for all $i$ and multiplying the relevant term by the number of ways to choose $\ell$ elements from a set of $r$ elements. We therefore have 
   \begin{equation}
   (\#)_{n_1,\ldots, n_r; k} =  \sum_{\ell=0}^{r}(-1)^{\ell}\, \binom{r}{\ell} \binom{m+r-1 - \ell(n+1)}{r-1},
   \end{equation}
   which matches the expression in the intuitive argument given by Thoma in "[Basic inclusion exclusion problem - picking 24 balls out of four sets of 10 balls](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171135/basic-inclusion-exclusion-problem-picking-24-balls-out-of-four-sets-of-10-ball)".

Comment: Wow, thanks for your extremely helpful and detailed answer! Very, very much appreciated!
To note for others - I think this formula only works if there are more than 1 distinct groups. For example, if you only have 1 distinct group (that contains 6 items .. so r = 1, x_1 = 6 and k = 3) and you're trying to form groups consisting of 3 items, the formula would give 0, though the real result would be 1

Comment: Actually the formula *would* produce 1. You have to remember that $\binom{n}{k}=1$ if $k=0$ as long as $n\geq1$. Therefore, with $r=1$, $n_1=6$, and $k=3$, only the first term in the formula will survive and that term would yield $\binom{\text{"something"}}{r-1} = 1$.

Comment: Also, if possible, could you expand on the IT problem which motivates this question? Maybe include it in the problem prompt. (I'm curious because I originally considered this question based on statistical mechanics concerns.)